# What are some specific examples of how to use the Swift 2 @convention(c) type annotation?

Tags: swift, swift2

I cannot seem to get Xcode 7 (beta) to accept me using the Swift 2 `@convention(c)` type annotation? Can someone please provide some specific syntactically correct usage examples of `@convention(c)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cFunction : @convention(c) (Int, Int) -> Int = { $0 + $1 }
```

Comment: Very funny :) I have heard of this "google" thing and actually went there. Show me a site from the first page or two that actually has what I asked for - an example of this usage.

Comment: Kametrixom - Can you use it (@convention(c)) when you define a function using the `func` keyword?

Comment: @ChrisMarkle I don't think you can, but it doesn't really matter since a closure is a function and behaves like one in every way. Sorry for the joke ;)

Comment: I'm trying to define this callback to present to VTCompressionSessionCreate() and getting an error. Thoughts as to why? `let callback : @convention(c) (a: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, b: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, c: OSStatus, d: VTEncodeInfoFlags, e: CMSampleBuffer?) -> Void = { return }` Error I get is: `... error: tuple types '(a: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, b: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, c: OSStatus, d: VTEncodeInfoFlags, e: CMSampleBuffer?)' and '()' have a different number of elements (5 vs. 0)`

Comment: @ChrisMarkle Your supplied closure `{ return }` has type `Void -> Void`. You should add parameters: `{ a, b, c, d, e in }` (The compiler crashes with the return)

Comment: `let callback : @convention(c) (a: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, b: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, c: OSStatus, d: VTEncodeInfoFlags, e: CMSampleBuffer?) -> Void = { a, b, c, d, e in }` crashes the compilation with or without the `return`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `@convention(c)` unless you are writing a hybrid app where Objective-C needs to call into your Swift code.

Here are two Swift method declarations:

```
func blockTaker(f:()->()) {}
func functionTaker(f:@convention(c)() -> ()) {}
```

Objective-C sees the first as taking an Objective-C block, and the second as taking a C pointer-to-function.

That is the distinction that `@convention(c)` draws.

Comment: What does the usage of `@convention(c)` in @Kametrixom's reply say?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I've answered the question. What I've said, I've said. You take it from there.

Comment: Ok @matt but you note that the the distinction that `@convention(c)` draws is that it defines a function as "as taking a C pointer-to-function" but I don't think that's what using it in a let statement as in @Kametrixom answer is saying.

Comment: What you think, you think. What I've said, I've said.

Comment: you always have neat answers @matt. Thanks for that